# Errors when copying part of a text file in python

Tags: python, file-io, text-files

I have the following code to copy a section of a text file to a new, temporary file. I am trying to create the temp file in the same directory as the file that is being copied. All of the print statements are to see how far it runs before crashing, pdb prints `1` and then give the error that is screencapped below the code.

```
def copymp(mptfile):
    print 1
    temp = os.path.dirname(mptfile) + '/mpdata.tmp'
    print 2
    mpfile = open(temp, 'w')
    print 3
    copyline = False
    for line in mptfile:
        print 4
        if line.startswith('MP'):
            copyline = True
            print 5
        if copyline:
            print 6
            print>>mpfile, line
            copyline = False
    mpfile.seek(1)
    return None
```

Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDtTI.jpg

Comment: That 4th print statement is going to give you an IndentationError if it executes that far.

Comment: I'm also confused about what you're trying to do. Why do you set copyline to true? Why don't you just directly print the line instead of having a copyline variable at all?

Comment: @RobVolgman: The indentation error would occur during compilation, before the code even starts to execute.

Comment: @RobVolgman the copyline part was redundant, I took it out. It was there in reference to [this daniweb thread](http://bit.ly/MKSQZa). All the prints were just for testing, and they are all gone now as well as it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter to `os.path.dirname()` must be a string, but you are apparently passing in a file object.  (Is this intended?)  Try

```
temp = os.path.dirname(mptfile.name) + '/mpdata.tmp'
```

instead.

(Side note:  You should look closely at the traceback you get.  The traceback shows in which line the error is occurring – no need for the print statements to isolate it.  In this case, you can see it's the call to `os.path.dirname()` that is failing, so you should check its documentation to diagnose the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [tempfile](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) module in python. Is it important that you create the tempfile in the same directory where the original file exists? If not, you can forget about the line where you try to get the path from the file object, or use as suggested:

```
temp = os.path.dirname(mptfile.name) + '/mpdata.tmp'
```

Anyway, most of the times you don't want to manage tempfiles yourself, that's why python's tempfile module exists.